# Highly Available out proc session server

Tags: session-state

Is there a way to have highly available session state server (out proc) so that if one of the server managing the session in db goes down, other can instantly come up and server the current user session. I can have a cluster of DB server but not sure if I can sync session information as well between the servers.

Comment: I am not very sure on state server but if you can use SQL server to store session information then that can be achieved using **AlwaysOn** feature of SQL server. This will always keep your secondary server in sync with primary server. and whenever your primary server goes down, secondary server will take the responsibility.

Comment: SQL AlwaysOn is manual failover so not very useful for this task. MongoDb and Redis session state managers are both capable of transparent failover.

Comment: Yes, I worked with azureRedis cache earlier for session managment but in this particular scenario, due to organizational policies, all the system should be onpremise. I do not want to go with maintaining redis cache standalone environment and hence looking for some oob options.